# Integrating custom kernel module into Debian

Tags: linux, debian, kernel-modules

I've built a kernal module from source and now would like to load the module at boot.

The .ko file is in the build directory in my user folder, and I know it works because running `insmod ./vizzini.ko` from the appropriate place works fine.

I made the directory `vizzini` in `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/kernel/drivers/` and copied the .ko file there.

Then I added `vizzini` to the end of `/etc/modules`.

However, when I run `modprobe vizzini`, the module is not recognised.

- Do I need to restart my computer (log out, log in again?)
- Can I use any name for the folder containing the .ko file?
- What permissions do I need?
- Is what I've done right so far?
- What else do I need to do?

Permissions are currently `-rw-r--r--  root root`

Comment: insmod is deprecated, use modprobe instead.

Comment: @schaiba You are right that insmod is less powerful than modprobe. Nevertheless, insmod is not deprecated (modprobe calls it) and it is easier to use if you want to test a fresh built kernel module before you install it since you do not need to run depmod for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems fine so far. You just need to run `depmod` - then `modprobe` should find your module.